# Optimize Join GreenPlum

Tags: sql, query-optimization, greenplum

I have table A with 20 million records. There is table B with 200,000 records.
I want to do a join like:

```
select *
from tableA a 
left join tableB b
on ((a.name1 = b.name1 OR a.name1 = b.name2) OR a.id = b.id)
and a.time > b.time
;
```

This is very time consuming.
I am using GreenPlum so I cannot make use of indexes.
How can I optimize this?
The number of rows in table B are incremental and will increase.

Comment: `I am using GreenPlum so I cannot make use of indexes.` If that is true you really should abandon Greenplum.

Answer (score 0):

Greenplum does support indexes. However, this query is a tricky since immaterial of what your distribution column is there is no way to co-locate the join for the following reason.

1. a.time or b.time is a bad candidate for distribution since it is a ">" operator
2. You could distribute tableA by (name1, id) and tableB by (name1, name2, id). But to see if the a.time > b.time is satisfied you needs to still see all tuples.

Not sure the query is a very MPP friendly one I am afraid.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).